# How to filter or delete parent node and make child node as parent node

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tree

I have a tree json, please check it below.
I want to delete parent node and make child node as parent node?
Or if I can is there any way to filter nodes from tree please look into below original json tree and expected json tree.

Original JSON IS

```
[
  {
    "Id": "224146",
    "Text": "Node One",
    "Depth": 0,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": false,
    "Nodes": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "224135",
    "Text": "Node two",
    "Depth": 0,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": false,
    "Nodes": [
      {
        "Id": "224136",
        "Text": "Client Summary",
        "Depth": 1,
        "IsSelected": false,
        "IsExpanded": false,
        "Nodes": [
          {
            "Id": "224137",
            "Text": "Manager 1",
            "Depth": 2,
            "IsSelected": false,
            "IsExpanded": false,
            "Nodes": [
              
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "224147",
    "Text": "Node three",
    "Depth": 0,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": false,
    "Nodes": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Value That I want IS.
Here I have remove Client Summary parent and make Manage 1 as parent.

```
[
  {
    "Id": "224146",
    "Text": "Node one",
    "Depth": 0,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": false,
    "Nodes": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "224135",
    "Text": "Node two",
    "Depth": 0,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": false,
    "Nodes": [
      {
        "Id": "224137",
        "Text": "Manager 1",
        "Depth": 2,
        "IsSelected": false,
        "IsExpanded": false,
        "Nodes": [
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "224147",
    "Text": "Node three",
    "Depth": 0,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": false,
    "Nodes": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

I want this solution dynamically because this is a sample json that i have posted here thanks in advance.

Thanks
Kushal shah

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to recursively traverse the whole hierarchy, and when you have a matching item, remove it from the array it is in, and insert at that position all the children items.

Here is a function that will perform such a node removal based on a given id.

```js
function remove(arr, delId) {
    const target = arr.findIndex(({Id}) => Id == delId);
    if (target >= 0) {
        arr.splice(target, 1, ...arr[target].Nodes);
    } else {
        arr.forEach(({Nodes}) => remove(Nodes, delId));
    }
}


// demo
const data = [{"Id": "224146","Text": "Node One","Depth": 0,"IsSelected": false,"IsExpanded": false,"Nodes": []},{"Id": "224135","Text": "Node two","Depth": 0,"IsSelected": false,"IsExpanded": false,"Nodes": [{"Id": "224136","Text": "Client Summary","Depth": 1,"IsSelected": false,"IsExpanded": false,"Nodes": [{"Id": "224137","Text": "Manager 1","Depth": 2,"IsSelected": false,"IsExpanded": false,"Nodes": []}]}]},{"Id": "224147","Text": "Node three","Depth": 0,"IsSelected": false,"IsExpanded": false,"Nodes": []}];
remove(data, "224136");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, but in this case it will work only one item delete, I have an array of ids which i want to delete? how it can work?

Comment: Iterate the array of ids, and call this function? Like `myArrayWithIds.forEach(id => remove(data, id))`

Comment: Let me check it and get back ton you if any, Thanks